# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in javascript function with json response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reply

This may seem a duplicate, but in my case it's a bit different.
I have the following code:

```
function stateList() {              
      function parseStateList(response){
        var stateTable= "<table><tr><td style='width: 500px; color: blue;'>Folder name (state)</td></tr>";
        console.log(response);
        statelist=response["States"];
        console.log(statelist);
        for (var i in statelist) {
            a = statelist[i];
            var index = Object.keys(statelist).indexOf(i)
            console.log("i="+index);
            console.log(statelist[i]);
            stateTable+="<tr><td style='width: 500px;'><button id=\""+index+"\" onclick=\"GetSavedState("+a+",parseSavedState)\">" + a + "</button></td></tr>";
            //document.getElementById(index).onclick = function(){GetSavedState(a,parseSavedState);};
        }
        stateTable+="</table>";
      document.getElementById('state_output').innerHTML = stateTable;
      }

      GetStateList(parseStateList);
    }
```

And I'm getting this error **SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

Comment: You sholuld also include the definition of `GetStateList`. Also, there should be a semicolon after `indexOf(i)`. I'll try reindenting your code to make sure the final curly is not out of place.

Comment: @amenadiel, thx for response, GetStateList is defined in functions.js and it executes only one thing - doRequest(params) with params. doRequest is also completely different function that is supposed to handle commands from client to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not in the code you've put in your question. I made a dummy `GetStateList` function and the snippet works fine. This points to the error being, for example, in the structure of the response you get from `GetStateList`.

PD: I took the liberty of quoting the first parameter of `GetSavedState` because you were passing it as a variable, whereas `a` is a string.

```js
function GetStateList(callback) {
  callback(
  {
    "States":{
      "CA":"California",
      "FL":"Florida"
    }
  });
}
function GetSavedState(stateusps, callback) {
   callback(stateusps);
}
function parseSavedState(savedState) {
   console.log(savedState);
}

function stateList() {
    function parseStateList(response) {
        var stateTable = "<table><tr><td style='width: 500px; color: blue;'>Folder name (state)</td></tr>";
        console.log(response);
        statelist = response["States"];
        console.log(statelist);

        for (var i in statelist) {
            a = statelist[i];
            var index = Object.keys(statelist).indexOf(i)
            console.log("i=" + index);
            console.log(statelist[i]);
            stateTable += "<tr><td style='width: 500px;'>";
            stateTable += "<button id=\"" + index + "\" onclick=\"GetSavedState('" + a + "',parseSavedState)\">" + a + "</button>";
            stateTable += "</td></tr>";
        }

        stateTable += "</table>";
        document.getElementById('state_output').innerHTML = stateTable;
    }

    GetStateList(parseStateList);
}

stateList();
```

```html
<div id="state_output"></div>
```

This doesn't answer your error, it's just a demonstration that it isn't where you think it is.

Comment: Awesome! Thx, this actually seems to work. I'm too Java oriented person it seems... In my opinion a is supposed to be a variable, but ok, i think i understand why it's a string